# api web en diferentes puertos

Tags: linux, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, net

Tengo un Api Web creada con net core 2.2, la cual esta en un servidor linux (OL7), y resuelve las peticiones usando un proxy inverso (apache) el cual llega finalmente al servicio que esta en un demonio con kestrel en el puerto por defaul (5000)
Necesito agregar otro servicio, con las mismas características, es decir, desde el apache, (en el puerto 86), redireccionar al nuevo servicio levantado en otro puerto diferente al 5000.
Mi problema, es que no encuentro como especificar el puerto en la api en net core 5.0
Alguna idea?.
Gracias por leer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes declarar la configuración en el archivo appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://localhost:5001"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Y después utilizarla en Program.cs

```
//using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core;
//using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
          Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
            {
                services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(
                  context.Configuration.GetSection("Kestrel"));
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
               webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

Para más formas de configurarlo, te dejo la documentación oficial
[Microsoft doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: gracias por la info.  ya solucione el problema tal como estaba en la info